# PFImageView missing in Parse 1.7.1 using cocoa pods

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, pfimageview

I am using the latest Parse SDK 1.7.1 for iOS and I installed it using cocoa pods. For some reason the class '`PFImageView`' (as found in the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFImageView.html)) is not included in the headers of the framework.

I realized it when I wanted to use the class as in this example:

```
- (UIImageView *)iconView {
  PFImageView *view = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithImage:kPlaceholderImage];
  view.file = self.iconFile;
  [view loadInBackground];
  return [view autorelease];
}
```

Does anyone know what happened to the `PFImageView` class or am I just doing something wrong? I am quite new to the Parse SDK.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you included the ParseUI import?

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem! I did not look into that framework, I assumed it would be in the Parse.h framework. I did have the ParseUI pod installed but had not imported it!

Answer (score 0):

[Adding comment from @soulshined as answer]

Add following to Podfile and run `pod install`

```
pod 'ParseUI'
```

Don't forget to `import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>`